# Linear regression least square method

Tags: numerical-methods

Right now, I'm studying linear regression using the least squares method. So, if $f(x)=ax+b$, I have to find
$$\min\sum(y-ax-b)^2.$$ But why does this minimum exist, and is there only one minimum or multiple of them?

Comment: the solution of the minimization of the LS problem exists and is unique because it is strongly convex ( hessian is positive definite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are minimizing
$$Q(a,b) = \sum (y_i -a x_i-b)^2.$$

Since $Q$ is a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$, any minimiser must be a stationary point, hence a solution of
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial a} = \sum 2 (-x_i)(y_i-ax_i-b) = 0
$$

$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial b} = \sum 2 (-1)(y_i-ax_i-b) = 0
$$

i.e.

$$
\begin{cases} 1\cdot b + \bar x \cdot a =& \bar y\\
\bar x \cdot b + \overline{x^2} \cdot a =& \overline{xy}
\end{cases}
$$

This is the so-called **normal system**. When $\overline{x^2}-\bar x^2\ne 0$, that is, when the variance is not zero, the system has one and only one solution. This solution must in fact be a global minimum, due to the convexity of $Q$. As it was pointed out, the Hessian matrix, given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2n & \sum x_i^2\\
2 \sum x_i &  2\sum x_i^2,
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is positive definite when the variance of $x$ is positive (just compute the minors' determinants).

Finally, you can try to figure out what happens when the variance is zero (all x's are the same).

Comment: thanks,but could you explain please how did you get the normal system?

Comment: For instance,
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial b} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum(y_y-ax_i-b)=0 \Leftrightarrow \sum y_i - a \sum x_i - nb = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac 1n \sum y_i - a \cdot \frac 1n \sum x_i  -b = 0$$

Comment: Now i got it.Thanks you very much